# Measuring contact between algebraic varieties

Tags: singularity-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I have two regular surfaces in three space, both of which are given by an equation. I would like to measure the contact between the two surfaces using only their equations. Usually, one would find a local parametrisation for one of the surfaces, and then substitute this into the other surface's equation. This would give a function in two variables, and the singularity type of this map would give the contact between the two surfaces. However, as I have mentioned: I only want to use the equations.

Is there a way to do this? For example, by looking at the dimension of some suitable ideal?

Comment: What do you mean by contact? Do you already know the surfaces are tangent?

Comment: The definition of contact is given above: it's the singularity type of the contact function, i.e. the composite of a parametrisation with a defining question. Consider for example, the contact between the plane $z=0$ and the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$. The contact function is $f(x,y,0)$. If the resulting contact function is non-zero then the surfaces don't intersect. If it does have a zero then the type of singularity at that zero gives the type of contact.

Comment: For example: a smooth surface has contact of type $A_1^+$ with its tangent plane at ordinary elliptic points and type $A_1^-$ at hyperbolic points. This means the contact function is $\mathscr{A}$-equivalent to $x^2 \pm y^2$. At ordinary parabolic points the contact is of type $A_2$, i.e. equivalent to $x^2 + y^3$. At umbilic points, the surface and its tangent plane have type $D_4^{\pm}$ meaning the contact function is $\mathscr{A}$-equivalent to $x^3 \pm xy^2$.

Comment: Your claim about the 'type' of umbilic points does not appear to be correct.  For example, the surface $z = x^2+y^2$ has an umbilic point at the origin (in the usual sense of differential geometry), but, by your definition of contact type, its contact with the tangent plane is of type $A^+_1$.  In general, notions such as 'umbilic' and 'contact with tangent plane' depend on geometric things that are not visible once you localize, and, in particular, are not well-defined under local (analytic) changes of coordinates.  Maybe you are regarding these surfaces as lying in projective 3-space? 

Comment: If two surfaces have contact of order $k$ at a point $p$ (i.e. have the same $k$-th jet at $p$) then their $k+1$-jets differ by a homogenous polynomial of order $k+1$ in two variables (after introducing a base in the tangent and normal space at $p$). Question: is the singularity type the equivalence class of this homogenous polynomial under the natural $GL(2)\times GL(1)$ action on the space of polynomials? (This interpretation might be compatibel with 3 out of the 4 examples in the OPs comment, but I don't know enough about the calssification of singularities and jargon in that area)

Comment: @Robert: Yes, you're right! The umbilics are given by $D_4^{\pm}$ of the contact function between the surface and an osculating sphere. The $D_4$ contact between a surface and a tangent plane is a flat umbilic, i.e. both parabolic and umbilic.

Comment: @Michael: The short answer is no. We parametrise a manifold in a neighbourhood of the contact point and compose this with the equation of the other manifold. The singularity type of the resulting function germ $(\mathbb{R}^n,0) \to (\mathbb{R},0)$ denotes the contact. The equivalence relation is $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence, i.e. diffeomorphic changes of independent and dependent variables. The simple contact types are $A_{\ge 1},$ $D_{\ge 4}$ and $E_6$, $E_7$ and $E_8$. Although there is a functional moduli zoo of many more, non-simple, orbits under the the action of $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

While I suspect that you are looking for some kind of homological algebra answer, here's a naive algorithm to get what you want:

Suppose that one is trying to determine the 'contact $k$-type' of a pair of algebraic surfaces at a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$.  One may as well assume that $p$ is the origin and let the surfaces be defined by polynomial equations $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$.

Of course, one must have $f(0,0,0)=g(0,0,0)$ or else the surfaces don't both pass through $p$.

Also, you are assuming that the 'surfaces are regular', by which, I am guessing that you want that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ don't vanish at $p$, so I'll assume that.  If $\nabla f\wedge\nabla g$ does not vanish at $p$, then the surfaces aren't tangent at $p$, so assume that $\nabla f\wedge\nabla g$ vanishes at $p$.  Under these assumptions, you can, by a linear change of coordinates, assume that $f$ has the form
$$
f(x,y,z) = z - f_2(x,y,z),
$$
where $f_2$ vanishes to order $2$ at $p=(0,0,0)$.  Then, of course, one has 
$$
g(x,y,z) = az + g_2(x,y,z)
$$
for some $a\not=0$ and some polynomial $g_2$ that vanishes to order $2$ at $p$.

Now define a sequence of polynomials $h_i(x,y,z)$ as follows:
$$
h_2(x,y,z) = g\bigl(x,y,f_2(x,y,z)\bigr)
$$
and, for $k\ge 2$,
$$
h_{k+1}(x,y,z) = h_k\bigl(x,y,f_2(x,y,z)\bigr).
$$
One can now prove, by induction, that, when one writes, for $k\ge 1$,
$$
h_{k+1}(x,y,z) = p_k(x,y,z) + R_{k+1}(x,y,z),
$$
where $p_k$ has degree at most $k$ and $R_{k+1}$ vanishes to order $k{+}1$ at $p$, then $p_k$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ only, and it defines the $k$-th order contact  type between the two surfaces at $p$.  (Of course, $p_1=0$.)

There is still the task of determining when two $p_k$'s are equivalent under change of variable in $x$ and $y$, but that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but how does this relate to the $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence of the contact function? (Usually defined as the composition of a parametrisation and a defining function).

Comment: I don't really know, since I don't have a precise definition of '$\mathscr{A}$-equivalence'.  I assume that this means 'equivalence up to formal changes of variables that fix the origin', but you should let me know if otherwise.

Comment: If you type "A equivalence" into Google then the first hit is a pretty good definition. As I mentioned: usually, we have two surfaces, one given by a parametrisation and one given by a defining equation. We substitute the parametrisation into the equation to give a function in two variables. $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence means that we allow diffeomorphic changes of variable in both the source and the target.

Comment: To bring things back into focus: I would like to know if there is a way to gain information about the singularity type of the contact function (the above composition) from then equations alone. I suspect that some algebraic consideration might suffice. For example, the dimension of a well-chosen ideal could give the Milnor number of the singularity type of the contact function. (The Milnor number of a function germ $f$ being the dimension of the local ring of function germs $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{R}^2,0}$, quotient the Jacobian ideal $\mathbb{R}\langle f_x,f_y\rangle$.)

Comment: In order to make sense of '$\mathscr{A}$-equivalence' according to the definition on the Wikipedia page, you need to specify a domain and a range.  Are you just taking the sequence of polynomials $p_k$, regarding them as pointed maps $p_k:\bigl(\mathbb{R}^2,0\bigr)\to\bigl(\mathbb{R},0\bigr)$, and asking for $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence in that sense?  For example, you might want to know that there is a $K>0$ such that all of the $p_k$ with $k\ge K$ are $\mathscr{A}$-equivalent.  (This would happen for $K=2$ if $p_2$ were a nondegenerate quadratic polynomial.)

Comment: Also, from your comment just above, it appears that you don't want to 'use the equations' the way I have to define the contact function.  Would you say that the algorithm I described in the above answer doesn't 'use the equations alone'?  I would have said that it does 'use the equations alone', but you appear to feel differently.  The point I was making is that you *can* derive a Taylor series for the contact function 'using the equations alone', which reduces the problem to studying $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence for a function of two variables, which is what I thought you wanted.

Comment: I'm not considering a sequence of polynomials. Your idea of contact seems to be different to mine. I'm already able to calculate the contact type using local parametrisations, e.g. formal power series, and then bring everything into a normal form. I was just looking for a different way to do it. I appreciate you taking the time to help, but I don't think we're going to make any progress here.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be so negative. Let $R$ be the ring of smooth function germs on a neighborhood of $p$, let $\mathcal{M}\subset R$ be the maximal ideal consisting of functions that vanish at $p$, and let the ideal $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{M}$ be generated by the defining equations $f$ and $g$ for the two surfaces. Then the ring $\bar R = R/\mathcal{I}$ contains a maximal ideal `$\bar{\mathcal{M}} = \mathcal{M}/\mathcal{I}$`, and the (finite dimensional) quotient rings `$\bar R_k=\bar R/{\bar{\mathcal{M}}}^k$` give information about your contact function. Is this the kind of thing you want? 

Comment: Let's try an example. Consider the parabola $2y−x^2=0$ and the circle $x^2+(y−r)^2−r^2=0$. When $r=1$, the circle is the oscillating circle to the parabola at the origin; if $r\neq 1$ then it is ordinarily tangent. Let's try two cases: $r=1,2$. In the first case we have $\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{R}^2,0} / (2y−x^2,x2+(y−1)^2−1)\cong \mathbb{R}\langle 1, x, x^2, x^3\rangle$. In the second case we have $\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{R}^2,0} / (2y−x^2,x2+(y−2)^2−4)\cong \mathbb{R}\langle 1, x, \rangle$ Interestingly, we get different quotient vector spaces! But the difference in dimension is two, not one...

Comment: I'm not sure why you find this surprising.  After all, because the parabola has a local maximum of its curvature at the vertex, it will have contact order at least 4 with its osculating circle there.  If you had done this calculation with some curve that didn't have a critical point of its curvature at the point in question, the difference in dimension would have been $1$.

Comment: Who said it was surprising? I said it was interesting, because I thought we might be getting somewhere. Obviously I already knew that the contact function has a degenerate singularity at a vertex -- that's why I chose the example! I was interested because I didn't expect the dimensions of the vector spaces to reflect this. Again, I think you misunderstand my standing.